# How do I change an Application Icon in the Applications Folder?

Tags: macos, applications, dock

I just installed an application and drag/dropped the file into the Applications folder. The application (or folder) icon is showing as some grayed out icon with a crossed-out circle over it in the Applications folder's stack in the Dock. This is not the application icon obviously. When I go to the Application Folder it displays correctly.

How do I make it display correctly in the Application Folder stack in the Dock? Is there a way to refresh it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon is shown on files that have been downloaded from the Internet and not used yet.

The first time you open the application, you will see a dialog warning you that you downloaded the application from the Internet and asking if you are sure you want to run it.
Say yes and run the app, and the icon should soon be changed back to what it should be (you may need to log out and back in).

---

To answer your question in general:

To change an app's icon, you first need to copy the new icon you want to use to the clipboard.

1. Open the image file you want in Preview (found in your Applications folder),
    select all (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and copy (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
2. Find the app whose icon you want to change. Select it in Finder and choose `File->Get Info` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).
3. Select the small preview icon in the top left of the Get Info window, and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

Is is a normal behavior for downloaded applications.

After having started the application one time and accepted to open it - log out and back in.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that. It's kind of silly that it doesn't do it after opening the first time. +1 Thanks.

Comment: @Rich Maybe just killing the dock is enough. Use `killall Dock` in `Terminal.app`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the program CandyBar to manipulate icons systemwide. It works for individual applications to. It has a trial period of 30 days, but it only counts the days that you use it. I have had my computer for 2 years and it has still not expired. I would recommend checking it out.

[CandyBar Website](http://panic.com/candybar/)