# How can I replace an application icon programmatically?

Tags: macos, icon

With the transition to Big Sur, the standard icon style for applications has changed to the rounded-square motif. Not a fan, I like to replace a few applications' icons with their older variants. I've typically done this with the "Get Info / Drag Icon" method (call it GIDI) similar to what is described in [this question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/how-do-i-change-an-application-icon-in-the-applications-folder). However, I'd like to automate the process instead of the manual one.

I've noticed that after the GIDI method, there is a file `Icon^M` in the application's root folder. I can't determine what kind of file it is since `file` doesn't recognize it and it has zero size; otherwise, I'd presume it to be a copy of the .icns file. Looking in the Application's Resources folder, I see that the GIDI method doesn't replace the application's standard icon, so something else is happening.

So that being said, what is the `Icon^M` file and is there a way I can do this replacement programmatically?

**Note:** I know that Apple's own applications that come with the macOS are protected under SIP and thus I would have to disable that for those icons. Those are out of scope for this; I'm only interested in 3rd party applications which *do not* require SIP to be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tool that makes this scriptable: [fileicon](https://github.com/mklement0/fileicon).

In short, if you have a .icns file you can do something like:

`bash$ fileicon set /Applications/Microsoft\ Word.app icon_i_prefer.icns`

...and it will do the resource fixing similar to what the 'Get Info / Drag Icon' routine I describe in the question does.

Problem solved!